# SQL join based on Chinese characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables of which I join but since the 2 columns contain Chinese characters, the `t1.term = t2.term` does not work.

```sql
select * 
from table t1
left join table t2 on t1.term = t2.term
```

- when I had to search by `like N'%'+ t1.term '%'` the 'N' did the work but I could not find how to implement it on the join `t1.term = t2.term`

Comment: Please provide example data and results. Just containing Chinese characters does not mean that an equality comparison won't work. You must have some differences in the values (or perhaps need to force a collation, but I don't know much about the latter).

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `like` expression in the `on` clause:

```
select *
from table t1 left join
     table t2
     on t2.term like N'%' + t1.term + N'%';
```

Note that this will kill performance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if the tables (/databases/schemas) are using the same collation, the collation is suitable to the content and the text is exactly the same, this should work.

Check you table/db/schema collation definitions and make sure the definitions are the same and are suitable for you textual content. The more insensitive your collation is, the more lenient it will be on differences e.g. text vs. TEXT, text vs. téxt, etc.